# Use date as primary key in Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, primary-key

I was thinking of using date as a primary key instead of the standard integer ID for a tracking app, however, there doesn't seem to be that much support for using non-integer primary keys in the rails documentation. Is this frowned upon? How would I do it and why should/shouldn't I consider it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails does support subtituting id with a custom column as the primary key, it can be of a string or integer type as far as I know.

Now,about your plan to use date type as the primary key, there are several things to note:

A primary key has to have these properties (at least in Rails):

- can not be null
- has to be unique
- has index

So does your date column fullfill all these properties? If not, then abandon your plan otherwise keep reading...

There are a lot of things that you have to configure (not following rails default) to use non-id as the primary key:

1. Migration file
2. Model class
3. Routes
4. Controller

You can check the link below for a comprehensive step-by-step guide:
http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Please keep in mind that Rails' mantra is convention over configuration, meaning that by straying from the convention you lose some of the advantages that Rails provides. If you accept the configurations and potential perils you may face ahead, at least reconsider the notion of using date as the column type and choose integer or string instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the philosophical issue of natural (data derived) and artificial (arbitrary value) keys.

As expounded in relational theory the *key* to a tupple (row) is the combination of data values contained therein that uniquely identify it.  For example: In a table of invoice detail lines the natural key to an invoice line might be the invoice number concatenated with the line number.  The remaining data, product, quantity, unit price, and so on, are uniquely accessed via that key.

The alternative is to simply assign a serial number to the row and place that in a specific field, typically named *id*, which has nothing to do with the data contained in the row.

Which is the superior method?  Well, that depends on many things. But let us look at the case of example given, the invoice line. Say it was invoice 20 and there are 10 lines.  We can imagine a key set looking something like this: 000020000001 through 000020000010. So, what happens when we delete line 6?  The the row having the key 000020000006 is removed.

Let us consider that the line numbers of invoices are printed thereon so that future customer inquiries may be referred to unambiguously. Now, what happens when we print the invoice?  Do we leave the gap in the line sequence when we print the invoice or do we close it up?  If we leave the gap then the last invoice line on our client's invoice will show 10.  This will imply to the casual reader that there are 10 lines on the invoice.  But line 6 is not there so only 9 lines are on the invoice.

The alternative is to renumber the remaining lines after the delete so that the former line 7 becomes line 6 and so on.  However, this changes the key value on those three lines and this means that all the other references to those rows must be updated as well.  This is going to create considerable overhead in any sort of real-life system and likely will be a constant source of error.

With an artificial key the id need never be visible outside the database.  Because of this once assigned it need never change. Therefore if the key to the invoice line is an arbitrary value one may freely update and renumber the invoice lines any way one see fit, say sorted in descending order by extended value, and all the internal references remain unaffected. One could change the invoice number as well, say in the case of a back-ordered item.

There is also the difficulty that often tupples are not fully normalised in a relational database design.  Or to obtain a natural unique key involves so much of the tupple's data that the tupple itself becomes the key.  In these cases natural keys either cannot provide the necessary unique qualities or their presence makes updating tupples in place excessively costly.

In practice artificial keys have proven to give both a guaranteed unique key and allow maximum flexibility with respect to modifying the contained data when compared to natural keys.  For these reasons artificial keys are widely employed and are considered by many to be the superior, or at least pragmatic, choice.

However, there are no absolutes. There are many cases where a natural key makes perfect sense (tables of codes for example) and the use of an artificial id is pointless.  None-the-less, in my experience, if a design uses artificial keys at all then they will be used everywhere.

This is the approach that RoR takes and for practical purposes it makes the most sense.  You can override the arbitrary key convention. The AR documentation provides more than adequate explanation of how to do so. I have overridden RoR primary keys in some projects but I never found an occasion where it was truly worth the effort.

One last note.  Many people confuse relational keys with indices.  A key is simply the means by which a relational system links set members.  It is not necessarily the preferred method of retrieving data from a database.  For that purpose one employs indices and then only if the cost of maintaining the index is less than the benefit obtained by the increase in retrieval speed over a simple serial search.  And an index value does not have to be unique, although that can be made a constraint if one so wishes.

Comment: "tuple", not "tupple"